# Guest VMs don't get IPs, how to troubleshoot network issue?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, routing, ip, kvm-virtualization

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.2, and KVM QEMU.

I have virtual machines configured as bridged (i.e. they should get their own IPs from the DHCP server and appear as separate hosts on the network.)

However, they're not getting any connectivity. I can't ping from them, and I can't ping to them. I would have expected them to get 169.xxx IPs if they can't get a DHCP lease, but they're not getting any IP at all instead.

I'm not sure why, and I can't fix it. I will format the machine and reinstall everything if I can't get it to work, but I'd much rather understand what the problem is and fix it instead.

Here are relevant commands and their output, as run on the host:

`$ ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1d:09:0b:87:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::21d:9ff:fe0b:876d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1d:09:0b:87:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.129/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::21d:9ff:fe0b:876d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: br-0e57a29cd0f7: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:2b:9a:39:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 scope global br-0e57a29cd0f7
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ed:8f:cb:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:edff:fe8f:cbc1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:41:79:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:41:79:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
16: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:81:08:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe81:8d0/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
32: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:72:c2:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe72:c2db/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
34: vethbae4bfe@if33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default 
    link/ether 72:a8:cd:d9:9c:fe brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::70a8:cdff:fed9:9cfe/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`$ ip l`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1d:09:0b:87:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1d:09:0b:87:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: br-0e57a29cd0f7: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:2b:9a:39:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ed:8f:cb:c1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:41:79:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:41:79:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
16: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:81:08:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
32: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:72:c2:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
34: vethbae4bfe@if33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 72:a8:cd:d9:9c:fe brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

`$ brctl show`

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br-0e57a29cd0f7     8000.02422b9a39d6   no      
br0     8000.001d090b876d   no      enp4s0
                            vnet0
                            vnet1
docker0     8000.0242ed8fcbc1   no      vethbae4bfe
virbr0      8000.52540041790f   yes     virbr0-nic
```

`$ virsh net-list --all`

```
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 default              active     yes           yes
```

`$ virsh net-dumpxml default`

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>42aa6628-f6c8-4169-9b38-1f6f5cbb7a04</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:41:79:0f'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

`$ virsh dumpxml downloader`

```
<domain type='kvm' id='9'>
  <name>downloader</name>
  <uuid>9241d93d-b403-4347-bdda-002b5ee8f344</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>1048576</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>524288</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>2</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-xenial'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact'>
    <model fallback='allow'>core2duo</model>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/media/storage/vm_disks/downloader.img'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'>
      <alias name='pci.0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <alias name='virtio-serial0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:72:c2:db'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <target dev='vnet1'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/2'/>
      <target port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/2'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/2'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0' state='disconnected'/>
      <alias name='channel0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='spice' port='5901' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
      <image compression='off'/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <alias name='sound0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <alias name='redir0'/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <alias name='redir1'/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <stats period='5'/>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x08' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='apparmor' relabel='yes'>
    <label>libvirt-9241d93d-b403-4347-bdda-002b5ee8f344</label>
    <imagelabel>libvirt-9241d93d-b403-4347-bdda-002b5ee8f344</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>
```

`$ cat /etc/network/interfaces`

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
# auto enp4s0
# iface enp4s0 inet manual

# VMs bridge
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports enp4s0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

`$ virsh net-start default

```
error: Failed to start network default
error: Requested operation is not valid: network is already active
```

`$ ip route`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev br0 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-0e57a29cd0f7  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.1.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.129 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

`$ iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  221.7.38.200         anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:http

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Can you do a dump for one of the Guests as well? Need to see what the network config was set for the VM.

Comment: Do you mean running the same commands but inside a guest?

Comment: While connected to the hypervisor: `virsh dumpxml <GuestID>`

Comment: Updated the question with the XML data for guest's config

Comment: Can you also provide your ip route list?

Comment: Also, can you verify the default network is up by doing virsh net-start default. Have you tried disabling the firewall to see if it's blocking DHCP?

Comment: added route list, and tried to start the network. I don't think there is any firewall up, I added the output of `iptables -L`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62049/discussion-between-user306802-and-ulfy).